# How to get all application link from the log text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have a log file which contains:

```
http://www.downloadray.com/windows/Photos_and_Images/Image_Convertors/
http://www.downloadray.com/windows/Photos_and_Images/Graphic_Capture/
http://www.downloadray.com/windows/Photos_and_Images/Digital_Photo_Tools/
```

I have this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urlparse

f = open("downloadray2.txt")
g = open("downloadray3.txt", "w")

for line in f.readlines():
    i = 1
    while 1:
        url = line+"?page=%d" % i
        pageHtml = urllib.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(pageHtml)

        has_more = 1
        for a in soup.select("div.n_head2 a[href]"):
            try:
                print (a["href"])
                g.write(a["href"]+"\n")
            except:
                print "no link"
        if has_more:
            i += 1
        else:
            break
```

This code do not give error but it do not working.
I tried modified it but can't solved it.
But when I try this code,it works well:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urlparse

g = open("downloadray3.txt", "w")

url = "http://www.downloadray.com/windows/Photos_and_Images/Image_Convertors/"
pageUrl = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageUrl)

i = 1
while 1:
    url1 = url+"?page=%d" % i
    pageHtml = urllib.urlopen(url1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageHtml)

    has_more = 2

    for a in soup.select("div.n_head2 a[href]"):
        try:
            print (a["href"])
            g.write(a["href"]+"\n")
        except:
            print "no link"
    if has_more:
        i += 1
    else:
        break
```

So how can I make it can read from the log text file. It is hard to take link one by one to be read.

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve from the pages?

Comment: when I run it `soup.select("div.n_head2 a[href]")` returns an empty list

Comment: @ChristianCareaga I want to take all the aplication link in soup.select("div.n_head2 a[href]"). As example, if http://www.downloadray.com/windows/Photos_and_Images/Image_Convertors/,the are a lot of application link.

Comment: well your code should work but your getting an empty list returned

Comment: @ChristianCareaga That is why I do not know why it happened.

Comment: why are you adding the `"&page=%d" % i`

Comment: Because there are so many pages inside the http://www.downloadray.com/windows/Photos_and_Images/Image_Convertors/

Comment: when i got to http://downloadray.com/windows/Photos_and_Images/Image_Convertors&page=1 i get a bad request response

Comment: @ChristianCareaga Its not '&' but '?'.I edited my question. The below code works well but if read from log then it wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you stripped the newline from the end of the line?

```
for line in f.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
```

`readlines()` will produce a list of lines taken from the file **including the newline `\n` character**.

<del>Proof</del> Evidence by printing `url` variable (after the line `url = line+"?page=%d" % i`):

Your original code:

```
http://www.downloadray.com/windows/Photos_and_Images/Image_Convertors/
?page=1
http://www.downloadray.com/windows/Photos_and_Images/Image_Convertors/
?page=2
http://www.downloadray.com/windows/Photos_and_Images/Image_Convertors/
?page=3
```

With my suggested fix:

```
http://www.downloadray.com/windows/Photos_and_Images/Image_Convertors/?page=1
http://www.downloadray.com/TIFF-to-JPG_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/Moo0-Image-Thumbnailer_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/Moo0-Image-Sizer_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/Advanced-Image-Viewer-and-Converter_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/GandMIC_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/SendTo-Convert_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/PNG-To-JPG-Converter-Software_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/Graphics-Converter-Pro_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/PICtoC_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/Free-Images-Converter_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/windows/Photos_and_Images/Image_Convertors/?page=2
http://www.downloadray.com/VarieDrop_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/Tinuous_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/Acme-CAD-Converter_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/AAOImageConverterandFTP_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/ImageCool-Converter_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/GeoJpeg_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/Android-Resizer-Tool_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/Scarab-Darkroom_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/Jpeg-Resizer_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/TIFF2PDF_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/windows/Photos_and_Images/Image_Convertors/?page=3
http://www.downloadray.com/JGraphite_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/Easy-PNG-to-Icon-Converter_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/JBatch-It!_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/Batch-It!-Pro_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/Batch-It!-Ultra_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/Image-to-Ico-Converter_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/PSD-To-PNG-Converter-Software_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/VectorNow_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/KeitiklImages_download/
http://www.downloadray.com/STOIK-Smart-Resizer_download/
```

**Update**:

Then again, this code won't run as expected, because the `while` loop will never continue since the `has_more` variable is never changed.

You know that you don't have more links when the list returned by `soup.select(...)` is empty. You can check for emptiness using `len(...)`. So that part might go like this:

```
    list_of_links = soup.select("div.n_head2 a[href]")
    if len(list_of_links)==0:
        break
    else:
        for a in soup.select("div.n_head2 a[href]"):
            print (a["href"])
            g.write(a["href"]+"\n")
        i += 1
```

Apparently the page still display the latest page available if it's queried beyond the maximum page. So if the maximum page number available is 82 and you query page 83, it will give page 82. To detect this case, you can save the list of previous page urls, and compare it with current list of urls.

Here is the full code (tested):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urlparse

f = open("downloadray2.txt")
g = open("downloadray3.txt", "w")

for line in f.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    i = 1
    prev_urls = []
    while 1:
        url = line+"?page=%d" % i
        print 'Examining %s' % url
        pageHtml = urllib.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(pageHtml)

        list_of_urls = soup.select("div.n_head2 a[href]")
        if set(prev_urls)==set(list_of_urls):
            break
        else:
            for a in soup.select("div.n_head2 a[href]"):
                print (a["href"])
                g.write(a["href"]+"\n")
            i += 1
            prev_urls = list_of_urls
```

Comment: nice man,it works. But why it stop at http://www.downloadray.com/Okdo-Gif-Jpg-Bmp-to-Tiff-Converter_download/ ? It dont want to go to next category.

Comment: because you never change the value of `has_more` and so the `while` loop never ends?

Comment: So how can I do that? I have no idea at all.

Comment: If you really wrote this code, I'm sure that you have some idea. Be confident! =) (and see my updated answer)

Comment: It still wont stop. I think this code cant be done for this page.

Comment: Hmm, after careful examination of your code, actually your code is incorrect. See my update.

Comment: Hmm, after careful examination of your code, actually your code is incorrect. Also the page actually produces the same content as you increase the `i`. In this case although the latest one is at page 82, if you query page 83 it will give you page 82. You probably want to detect the end by comparing the list of URLs with the previous page?

Comment: yes,the page will produce the same content after the last page.

Comment: I used that for testing only.

Comment: Great, hope that helps. =)